# Hacer dos consultas a dos tablas y obtener resultados independientes mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Necesito una ayuda sobre un problema. Tengo dos tablas: 1ra `entradaqueso` con un campo `cantidad` y 2da `salidaqueso` con un campo `cantidad`. Lo que quiero es hacer la suma `entradaqueso.cantidad` obtener el resultado y `salidaqueso.cantidad` obtener el resultado. 
El problema de mi consulta es que me devuelve valores dobles, es decir, si en cantidad tengo `100+100` me devuelve `400` cuando debería ser `200`; y la otra columna lo mismo, me devuelve el doble. Necesito una consulta que me traiga el valor de las dos cantidades por separado, es decir, según el ejemplo: `200` y `95`. Muchas gracias por su atención.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Pues en buen mysql debería ser algo como:

```
select 
    (
      select sum(cantidad) 
      from entrada_queso
    ) as entradaqueso, 
    (
      select sum(cantidad) 
      from salida_queso
    ) as salidaqueso
```

Al hacer esto estás utilizando 2 subconsultas y el resultado de cada una de ellas le colocas un nombre. Los `sum` hacen una suma de los valores del campo especificado de todos los registros de la tabla de cada subconsulta.

Comment: Eftshiftt0 si señor esa también sería la solución exactamente. La solución estaba en el uso de las benditas subconsultas .me resultó de maravilla muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score -1):

La solución fue más fácil de lo que pensé: estoy utilizando Jasper Reports y así quedó mi sentencia que resolvió mi problema:

```
SELECT
     ( SELECT SUM(entradaqueso.`cantidad`) FROM `entradaqueso` entradaqueso )AS entradaqueso_cantidad,
     ( SELECT SUM(salidaqueso.`cantidad`) FROM `salidaqueso` salidaqueso )AS salidaqueso_cantidad,
     entradaqueso.`identradaqueso` AS entradaqueso_identradaqueso,
     entradaqueso.`fecha` AS entradaqueso_fecha,
     entradaqueso.`costo` AS entradaqueso_costo,
     entradaqueso.`total` AS entradaqueso_total,
     salidaqueso.`idsalidaqueso` AS salidaqueso_idsalidaqueso,
     salidaqueso.`fecha` AS salidaqueso_fecha,
     salidaqueso.`valor` AS salidaqueso_valor,
     salidaqueso.`total` AS salidaqueso_total
FROM
     `entradaqueso` entradaqueso,
     `salidaqueso` salidaqueso
```